# Rails check_box_tag checked according boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my db, I've a boolean field: `is_in_city`.

In view, I try to set `check_box_tag` as:

```
= check_box_tag c.is_in_city
```

But it is never checked even if the db value is true. What is wrong?

I need to do such `chekbox`, which is no/is checked according to db boolean field value stored in the database. How can I do this? Also how can I set one more my property to checkbox?

Comment: Did you try `<%= check_box_tag :is_in_city %>`?

Comment: @mbratch ofcourse i tried

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The proper use of the `check_box_tag` method is like this:

```
= check_box_tag :name, value, checked
```

Where `value` can be anything, `checked` (should be) a boolean.

In your case:

```
= check_box_tag :is_in_city, 1, c.is_in_city
```

Documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag